# Crear dinámicamente un formulario

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando crear dinámicamente un formulario insertado dentro de una `template`:

```
<template id="temp-form">
    <form method="post">
        <div id="content-form">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="formLOGOSTariff.sndFrm()">UPDATE TEXTAREA</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="formLOGOSTariff.addFrm()">+</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="formLOGOSTariff.delFrm()">-</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

Estoy intentando agregarlo a través de la función `initL()`:

```
initL(){
      var temCard    = document.querySelector("#temp-card").innerHTML;
      var temPower   = document.querySelector("#temp-power").innerHTML;
      var temEnergy  = document.querySelector("#temp-energy").innerHTML;

      //Generar formulario dinámicamente
      var temForm    = document.querySelector("#temp-form").innerHTML;

      var contentForm= document.querySelector("#content-form");

      let foorm = document.createElement("form");
         foorm.innerHTML = temForm;
         document.querySelector("#temp-form");
         temForm.appendChild(foorm);
         foorm.appendChild(contentForm);

      let card = document.createElement("div");
         card.innerHTML = temCard;
         contentForm.appendChild(card);

      let power = document.createElement("div");
         power.innerHTML = temPower;

      let energy = document.createElement("div");
         energy.innerHTML = temEnergy;

            card.querySelector(".container-power").appendChild(power);
            card.querySelector(".container-energy").appendChild(energy);
   }
```

La cual se ejecuta cuando la página se carga:

```
window.addEventListener("load",()=>{
   var nomVre = new formLOGOSTariff();
   nomVre.initL();
});
```

Pero no obtengo otro resultado mas que errores.

**Resultados:**

- `temForm.appendChild()` is not a function [Tal y como está el código]
- Quitando `foorm.appendChild(contentForm);` retorna contentForm is null

Si quito la template, y el intento de crear dinámicamente el formulario, me da una funcionalidad el 100% de lo que quiero.

¿Cómo puedo crearlo bien?

Answer (score 0):

Hecho:

```
   initL(){
      var temCard    = document.querySelector("#temp-card").innerHTML;
      var temPower   = document.querySelector("#temp-power").innerHTML;
      var temEnergy  = document.querySelector("#temp-energy").innerHTML;
      var temForm    = document.querySelector("#temp-form").innerHTML;

      let foorm = document.createElement('div');
         foorm.innerHTML = temForm;
         document.body.appendChild(foorm);

      var contentForm   = document.querySelector("#content-form");
      console.log(contentForm);

      let card = document.createElement("div");
         card.innerHTML = temCard
         contentForm.appendChild(card);

      let power = document.createElement("div");
         power.innerHTML = temPower;

      let energy = document.createElement("div");
         energy.innerHTML = temEnergy;

            card.querySelector(".container-power").appendChild(power);
            card.querySelector(".container-energy").appendChild(energy);

   }
```

El error se basaba en que no estaba creando el `foorm`, tenía que hacer un `document.body.appendChild(foorm);`

¡Y LISTO!

Comment: y de paso, `tempForm` es string y estabas llamando `appendChild` sobre ésta